# How do I select just any one row of multiple instances?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table that looks something like this

| city | num | something |
| --- | --- | --- |
| LA | 1233 | av |
| NYC | 1233 | ad |
| ATL | 1233 | ac |
| SF | 426 | ah |
| Hollywood | 426 | ap |

and I want something like this where we just pick one row of all the distinct nums but only one.

| city | num | something |
| --- | --- | --- |
| LA | 1233 | av |
| SF | 426 | ah |

What query method would be most effective at getting the second table?

I chose LA 1233 av at random. I do not care what specific instance of 1233 that I get, just that I only get.

Comment: What's the rule that made you pick the `LA / 1233` row over the other rows with the same `num` value?

Comment: Look into a Rank() over (partition by num) example. I'm not a redshift user, but would assume it supports Rank.

Comment: @marc_s no rule, I do not care which one is picked for city, just that one and only instance of num gets picked per unique num values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way :

```
select * from ( 
   select * , row_number() over (partition by num order by random()) as rn
   from tablename
) t where rn = 1
```

which return random select each time , but if you don't care use a column like `city` in your order by clause.